# Detecting system wake event using Dbus in linux

Tags: 20.04, dbus, events

I wanted to perform some task in my application, as soon as the application wakes from sleep mode. To do that I wanted to detect the wake event in my application. I m detecting the sleep event in my cpp program using the below code. Can someone help on how to detect the wake event in cpp, like what DBus signal to use because I m not able to find anything online.

```
#include <dbus/dbus.h>

static DBusHandlerResult handleSleepSignal (DBusConnection * connection, DBusMessage * message, void * user_data) 
{
  std::cout << "System is going to sleep." << std::endl;
  return DBUS_HANDLER_RESULT_HANDLED;
}

int main () 
{
  DBusError err;
  dbus_error_init( & err);

  // Connect to the session bus
  DBusConnection * connection = dbus_bus_get(DBUS_BUS_SESSION, & err);

  // Add a match rule to listen for signals indicating events
  const char * match_rule = "type='signal',interface='org.freedesktop.login1.Manager',member='PrepareForSleep'";

  dbus_bus_add_match(connection, match_rule, & err);

  // Specify the callback function to handle sleep signal

  dbus_connection_add_filter(connection, handleSleepSignal, nullptr, nullptr);

  // Enter the main event loop
  while (true) {
    dbus_connection_read_write_dispatch(connection, -1);
  }

  // Cleanup
  dbus_connection_unref(connection);

  return 0;
```